# globally installed eslint not showing errors in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

i want to use eslint but i dont want to have to configure it for every single project

here is what i did:

1. installed the eslint vscode extension
2. installed eslint globally via `npm install -g eslint`

i've restarted vscode and it still won't show any errors in my js files

expecting it to show js errors

Comment: Is there a `eslint` configuration file in the root of your project, like `.eslintrc`?

Comment: no, like i said i want to configure it globally so i dont need to do it for every project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you have already installed `eslint` globally by `npm install -g eslint`, the next step is to have a global eslint configuration.

1. Head to https://eslint.org/play/
2. Under the `Rules` tab, select the rules you want to use (besides the default rule already added):
   [image]
3. Click on the `Add this Rule` link to add that rule.
4. Once you are finished adding all the rules you want, scroll the bottom, and click on the `Download this config file`.
   [image]

You now have a `eslintrc.json` file!

5. The next step is to add this as a global ruleset for your `.js` file.

Head to your home directory:

```
MacOS: /Users/{USERNAME}
Linux: /home/{USERNAME}
Windows: C:\Users\{USERNAME}
```

**Copy this file as `.eslintrc.json` to your home directory.** (notice the `.` at the start)

6. Restart VS Code.

Do note that if any of your projects have a local `eslint` configuration, then that configuration shall be used instead of the global configuration we just created.

Comment: so i absolutely need a eslint config file, even tho i just wanna use all default eslint settings?

Comment: Yes. You need to keep 1 default eslint config at the very least. But this way, you dont have to use separate eslint config for each of your projects